# Passing parameters to AXIS web service

Tags: java, axis

I have an AXIS servlet which deployed on an apache tomcat server on windows. 
I wrote a web service which I want to run on AXIS. 
When I want to deploy my web service, I make a jar file from the classes, and then I copy them to "axis\WEB-INF\lib" directory. Then I deploy the web service using a wsdd file.
My question is - how can I pass parameters to the web service, and how can I read them?
The only web.xml file that I have, is the AXIS web.xml file. Should I put them there?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using something as old as Axis for a new system?

Comment: It's not a new system... I have to maintain it :-/

Answer (score 0):

I came across with exactly same issue.  I have a not so perfect solution.  I am using a properties file to store params and access this properties file in the service classes.  I am facing problem when I put all my classes in to a jar file.  I am able to access properties file in my service class if I place properties file inside the jar file.  I am unable to access properties file (without hardcoding the path) when I place it outside jar file.  For maintainance point of view it is good practice to keep properties file accessible easyly.

-Rao